# Cannot run npm install only on this project

Tags: node.js

I have run npm install many times on this project in the past and I know that it should work just fine. That being said I cannot run npm uninstall either but only on this project. I know this isn't a lot to go on, has anything changed with the format or is something incorrectly formatted?

When I run `npm install` it takes maybe 10 seconds and then I get this message.

> npm ERR! code UNKNOWN npm ERR! UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'D:\TFS
>   Source\xxx\xxx\node_modules.bin\ngc'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
>   C:\Users\Bailey
>   Miller\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-12-27T14_41_52_431Z-debug.log

Side note: the ngc file is empty, and none of my text editors can open it. The debug log file is so long and has no clear way of finding errors.

package.json: *Snippet*

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^4.2.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.2.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.2.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.2.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.2.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.2.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.2.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.28",
    "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
    "@ngrx/db": "^2.0.2",
    "@ngrx/effects": "^2.0.4",
    "@ngrx/router-store": "^1.2.6",
    "@ngrx/store": "^2.2.3",
    "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^3.2.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.6",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "reselect": "^3.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.2",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.2.5",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.6.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.6",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "8.0.10",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "karma-ie-launcher": "^1.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "ngrx-store-freeze": "^0.1.9",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.5.0",
    "typescript": "~2.2.0"
  }
```

Comment: The information from `C:\Users\Bailey Miller\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-12-27T14_41_52_431Z-debug.log` could be very useful. Also, try running `npm update -g`.

Comment: If you need access to the log file I will post it to my OneDrive.

Comment: I hate node very much it is a really complicated thing to learn. It has so many weird little things that can throw it off and it gives me so many headaches.

Comment: @fingeron running npm update -g ran and updated stuff but still cannot run npm install.

Comment: Nothing is perfect :). It doesn't seem like the problem is with your package.json, I mean, it's missing a lot of basic parameters but you're being thrown off with a more generic error that looks like it comes from NPM itself. I suggested `npm update -g` to see if it might fix those broken parts. Maybe a related file was edited/removed by mistake? Try re-downloading the Node.js MSI and run an installation fix.

Comment: I already updated to the recommended version of node. I have version control but none of the files that are connected to my packages have been edited recently.

Comment: I am going to uninstall node, reboot, reinstall, and see how it goes.

Comment: Can you run "npm install" in a different project? I never tried so I can't tell for sure, but maybe it's related to the basic `package.json` configuration properties that are missing?

Comment: Yes I can run run npm install in other projects, all their package.json files look very similar though.

Comment: I just read in their docs and apparently a `package.json` must contain "name" and "version", as they're crucial for NPM as a package manager. Please append those properties and update me.

Comment: What I am showing is just a snippet of the package.json file I have those at the top.

Comment: Oh, that would have been an important mention. Try running `npm install <specific package name>` in the same folder and I believe we'll then have a better idea of what's going on.

Comment: I am trying something, I deleted the package.lock.json file and so far doing an npm install is working well.

Comment: That did it, deleting the package.lock.json file running npm update && npm install. Everything worked like a charm.